# How to use a Java Script file with JQuery functions in my Blazor project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I found a good Html template with CSS and JS script and I want to use it for my Blazor WASM project. The problem is that that JS functions don't work.

I tried a lot of things like:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("...(i tryed a lot of things here)");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe you have any idea?
Here is the JS script : https://pastebin.com/YXjuCW4A

Comment: There is no function named `sidebarFunc` defined in the JS you've linked to. Also note that, if there was, it would need to be in global scope, not defined within the `(function window($) { /* ... */ })(jQuery);` IIFE

Comment: I am new to JS so i tryed to modify a little bit the script in this way : 
$('<a href="#sidebar" class="toggle">Toggle</a>')
    .appendTo($sidebar)
    .on('click', function sidebarFunc(event){

     // Prevent default.
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

     // Toggle.
      $sidebar.toggleClass('inactive');

    });